# Use the same multiple sequence several times

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have a list of 3 numbers I'd like to iterate several times over in my document, and be able to change them once and for all if needed.

Here's an ugly example that reproduces what I'm doing right now:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\x/\y in {{1/0/0},{2/5/0},{5/0/-3.7},{7/5/-3.7}}{
\node at (\x,\y) {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\x/\y in {{1/0/0},{2/5/0},{5/0/-3.7},{7/5/-3.7}}{
\node at (\x,\y) {Again\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I wanted to use:

```
\newcommand{\myseq}{{1/0/0},{2/5/0},{5/0/-3.7},{7/5/-3.7}}
```

to achieve that but apparently tikz then tries to compute `1/0` because compiling returns:

```
Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `1' by `0', but I cannot divide any number by `0' (in '1/0/0').
```

What would be a the right way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no error:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\x/\y in {1/0/0,2/5/0,5/0/-3.7,7/5/-3.7}{
\node at (\x,\y) {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newcommand\myseq{1/0/0,2/5/0,5/0/-3.7,7/5/-3.7} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\x/\y in \myseq {
\node at (\x,\y) {Again\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I removed the unnecessary braces in the data, but they cause no harm).

You probably did

```
\foreach \i/\x/\y in {\myseq} {
```

which is wrong.

Comment: Wow. I did not even give the part that was messing it up and you fixed it. Thanks!